# How to use Azure functions with partial classes

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have the following Azure Function implemented as partial c# class which spans two files.

myfunction.cs and myfunction.mypartial.cs

```
public static partial class MyFunction
{        
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> MyFunction(
                           [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "GET", Route = "myfunction/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
                           ILogger log, int id)
    {
       // DO SOME STUFF       
    }
}
```

If the implementation of MyFunction is located in myfunction.mypartial.cs it is not detected by the Azure Function runtime.

Does Azure Function not support partial classes?

Comment: why are you creating a Partial class?

Comment: and I think Function app doesn't support partial classes (Not able to find any documentation for this).

Comment: Hi @ManishTiwari I want to break up the methods into different files for clarity. The function may have alot of methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My test was successful:

**First file:**

```
    public static partial class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Sample1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Sample1(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
```

**Seconde file**

```
    public static partial class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Sample2")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Sample2(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
```

Please find my working solution on GitHub:
https://github.com/MarkusMeyer13/PartialFunction